# How to filter an Actor object?

Tags: swift, actor

I have an `Actor` object that I want to be able to iterate and filter.

```swift
actor DataModel {
    typealias Details = (passed: Bool, scores: [Int])
    private(set) var data: [Int: Details] = [:]

    func update(_ value: (Bool, [Int]), forKey key: Int) {
        data.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    subscript(id: Int) -> Details? {
        get {
            data[id]
        }

        set {
            data[id] = newValue
        }
    }

    func removeAll() {
        data.removeAll()
    }
}

extension DataModel: AsyncSequence, AsyncIteratorProtocol {
    typealias Element = (key: Int, value: Details)

    func next() async throws -> Element? {
        var iterator = data.makeIterator()
        return iterator.next()
    }

    nonisolated func makeAsyncIterator() -> Data {
        self
    }
}

let data = DataModel()
await data.update((false, [1, 2]), forKey: 0)
```

But, whenever I use the `filter` method, it goes into an infinite loop.

```swift
let filtered = data.filter { el in
    /// infinite loop
    return el.value.passed || el.value.scores.count > 3
}

for try await i in filtered {
    print(i)
}
```

**Update**

Created a separate iterator, but getting the following error:

> Actor-isolated property 'data' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context

```swift
extension DataDetail: AsyncSequence {
    typealias Element = (key: Int, value: (passed: Bool, scores: [Int]))
    typealias AsyncIterator = DataInterator

    nonisolated func makeAsyncIterator() -> DataInterator {
        return DataInterator(data) /// Actor-isolated property 'data' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context
    }
}

struct DataInterator: AsyncIteratorProtocol {
    typealias Detail = (key: Int, value: (passed: Bool, scores: [Int]))

    private let details: [Int: (passed: Bool, scores: [Int])]
    lazy var iterator = details.makeIterator()
    
    init(_ details: [Int: (passed: Bool, scores: [Int])]) {
        self.details = details
    }
    
    mutating func next() async throws -> Detail? {
        let nextDetail = iterator.next()
        return nextDetail
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't name your custom types the same as existing built-in types to avoid any unexpected issues. There is already a Data type so I would suggest you rename your actor.

Comment: That's true. I just renamed it to simplify the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your `next()` method. You're creating a new iterator on each call, so every call to your `next()` method is effectively returning `data.first` over and over again. It'll never hit `nil`, so it'll never end.

I'm not sure what the easiest way to fix it is, however. You can't just `return data.makeIterator()` from `makeAsyncIterator()`, because `data` is actor-isolated.

You'll probably want to make a new  `AsyncIteratorProtocol`-conforming struct which wraps your actor and vends the elements of its `data` in an actor-isolated way

Comment: Thank you. Took your advice and updated the question, but not sure how to go about addressing the actor-related property issue.

Comment: @Kevvv Either you need your `DataInterator` to wrap the `Data` actor (so that it can call its actor-isolated functions safely), or if you want it to wrap the `data: [Int: Details]`, you'll need to make it an actor itself